# Writing play based on translated poem

Tags: copyright

I am currently writing a short 10 minute play adaptation of Layla and Majnun, a poem written in the 12th century by Nizami. To do this I am making use of an English translation of the Persian poem by Rudolph Gelpke with Zia Inayat Khan and Omad Safi.

Throughout the play, I wish to use direct quotations or slightly altered quotations from the translated text. Is this allowed?

Comment: What is the date and place of publication of the translation of the poem?

Comment: The translation has ISBN  978-0930872526 and was published in 1996, as a quick Google search shows. It is surely under copyright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the 12th century original is in the public domain, that translation was, if I am correct, published in 1996 and is protected by copyright. You will not be able to use extensive quotations without permission from the copyright holders. If you are in the US, you could probably use limited quotations under [Fair Use](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32422/is-this-copyright-infringement-is-it-fair-use-what-if-i-dont-make-any-money-o). Exactly how much could be used depends on the specific facts -- there is no general rule. If your use would be likely to harm the market for the translation or to replace it, that would weigh against a finding of Fair Use, but there are four factors and they must all be considered. Note that fair use is a very specifically US concept, and will not apply elsewhere.