# Do I need permission from the media company if I want to write a news article from the same topic, using the original article as the only source?

Tags: is-x-legal, media

Suppose I want to write an article from a topic and there is an article that I want to use as the only source (I know that's not ideal, but this is just a hypothetical situation). The facts would 100% come from the original article, I would just rephrase them. Would this be allowed (if given credit) or do I need some extra permission from the media company to do that?

Related (Not the same, since I'm not asking about needing to give credit. I want to give credit.): [Do I need to give credit to the original writer if I rewrote something in my own words?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79799/do-i-need-to-give-credit-to-the-original-writer-if-i-rewrote-something-in-my-own)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copyright does not protect facts. If you use the media article as a source for facts, but restate them in essentially different words and with a different organization, you need no permission.

Ethically you should cite your source, and attribute any brief quotes, but that is probably not legally required.