# At what point is using a song's instrumental considered fair use?

Tags: copyright, fair-use, parody

Let's say someone want to make a song using the instrumental of Just the two of us by Grover Washington...

Maybe half the song is humorous about the bad and good parts of a relationship..but the other half is more serious would it then be considered parody and be subject to fair use under copyright law?

How would you advise this person to proceed if they were dead set on using the instrumental and trying to minimize the likelihood that they would get sued by the copyright owner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this copyright infringement? Is it fair use? What if I don't make any money off it?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32422/is-this-copyright-infringement-is-it-fair-use-what-if-i-dont-make-any-money-o)

Comment: Short answer: it's a multifactor balancing test, there's no bright-line rule, every case gets judged independently.

Answer (score 1):

### How do you parody an instrumental?

Is your arrangement for the kazoo and the calliope withe whoopie cushion noises? Is it a marching band tune that you are scoring for the piccolo and the mouth harp for comedic effect?

Remember that the lyrics and the music are two independent works as well as a joint work and while it is relatively easy to parody the lyrics, and possible to parody both, it is much harder to parody the music on its own.

In any event, it seems that what you are talking about is [satire, not parody](https://copyrightalliance.org/faqs/parody-considered-fair-use-satire-isnt/). You are making fun of relationships: that’s satire. To be a parody, you have to be making fun of the *song*. Parody is fair use, satire isn’t.

> In fact, when examining how copyright law protects parody the Supreme Court explained in Campbell v. Acuff-Rose Music, Inc., “Parody needs to mimic an original to make its point, and so has some claim to use the creation of its victim’s (or collective victims’) imagination, whereas satire can stand on its own two feet and so requires justification for the very act of borrowing.”

If your critique of relationships would be just as valid set to other music, you don’t have a fair use defence.

Note that what is protected is “criticism or comment” which can be a humorous parody but can also be serious. The guide is not if it’s funny, it’s if it criticises or comments on the original work.

Answer (score 0):

Fair use is assessed using [a statutory, four-factor test](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement), codified at [17 USC § 107](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107).

The factors to be assessed are:

1. the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;
2. the nature of the copyrighted work;
3. the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole; and
4. the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of the copyrighted work.

You ask:

> At what point is using a song's instrumental considered fair use?

There is no objective cutoff point at which a person can be certain what they've copied would be defensible as fair use. Every circumstance is assessed case-by-case.

However, I will emphasize a few things:

- Every one of the statutory factors *must* be considered.
- In particular, the "amount and substantiality" factor must be considered in every fair-use analysis.
- No single factor is determinative.
- "[Some courts have found use of an entire work to be fair under certain circumstances. And in other contexts, using even a small amount of a copyrighted work was determined not to be fair because the selection was an important part—or the 'heart'—of the work.](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/)"
- The "amount and substantiality" factor "calls for thought not only about the quantity of the materials used, but about their quality and importance, too" (*Campbell v. Acuff-Rose Music, Inc.*, [510 U.S. 569](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/510/569/), 587).
- The "amount and substantiality" factor asks whether what was taken is "reasonable in relation to the purpose of the copying" (*Campbell*, 586).
- "The extent of permissible copying varies with the purpose and character of the use" (*Campbell*, 586).
- "There are no absolute rules as to how much of a copyrighted work may be copied and still be considered a fair use" (*Sundeman v. the Seajay Society, Inc.*, [142 F.3d 194](https://casetext.com/case/sundeman-v-the-seajay-society-inc) (4th Cir. 1998).
- "There is ample precedent supporting a finding of fair use when the amount taken was necessary to accomplish the second work's transformative purpose" (Jeremy King, "[Tiny, Tiny Copyright: An Examination of the Copyrightability of Sampler Instruments and Its Impact on Derivative Works](https://journals.library.columbia.edu/index.php/lawandarts/article/view/8955)" (2021) Columbia J. Law & Arts, citing *Authors Guild, Inc. v. HathiTrust*, 755 F.3d 87 (2d Cir. 2014); *A.V. ex rel. Vanderhye v. iParadigms, LLC*, 562 F.3d 630 (4th Cir. 2009); *Fox
  News Network, LLC v. TVEyes, Inc.*, 43 F. Supp. 3d 379 (S.D.N.Y. 2014)).

From those premises one has to conclude that the point at which using only a song's instrument track would be considered fair use *will not* necessarily be at "[exactly the same point as using the full version](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97936/at-what-point-is-using-a-songs-instrumental-considered-fair-use/97946#97946)." There is clearly room for circumstances in which taking instrumentals only would be considered fair use but taking the complete track would not be considered fair use.

We cannot tell you where those points would be in the abstract.

Answer (score -1):

> At what point is using a song's instrumental considered fair use?

At exactly the same point as using the full version.

That said, only using the instrumental component of a song does not secure you any leeway whatsoever: the component is copyrighted to no lesser extent than the whole.

Comment: I doubt there's any law that will support this assertion. If part of the analysis asks whether the alleged infringer copied "too much," I don't see how borrowing 100 percent of the words can be legally indistinguishable from borrowing 0 percent of the words.

Comment: @Jen The "amount" (the total length of the track) will be unchanged. And you seem to be highly diminishing the substantiality or song instrumentals: the vocals rarely occupy the bulk of it.

Comment: @Jen cite some case law re length/amount/substantiality (I may be convinced to delete this answer).

Comment: @Jen Thanks, I'll take a look. But I disagree that I "should" have done the research. Whilst it may have been apt, there is no such requirement here. Members are free to post answers on their own terms (pretty much like they are free to vote, and mods are free to delete). Nothing to be shocked about.

Comment: @Jen In [_Campbell_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell_v._Acuff-Rose_Music,_Inc.), the parody only sampled the bassline from the original (as opposed to using the full instrumental as posed in the question). [_Harper_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harper_%26_Row_v._Nation_Enterprises) was held not fair use, so it doesn't contradict the implication of my answer that using only the instrumental won't be fair use. Thus, the answer stands (unless someone cites cases proving it wrong to my satisfaction).

Comment: @Jen I do not see any sources saying that it "is not true". Surely the "amount and substantiality" generally matter, but I am confident that the complete instrumental of a typical song is virtually as substantial as the whole for the purposes of the fair use test, and I am not aware of any law proving this assertion wrong. Nor am I of the view that the burden of proving it right by citing sources lies on me.

Comment: @Jen I am not saying that a court would fail to consider amount and substantiality. Rather, it would hold that the amount/substantiality of the complete instrumental of a song is not materially different from that of the whole song. Unless there is a case proving this assertion wrong, I stand by my answer — yes, in the absence of cases proving it right. This is the approach I often take in my answers, shocking or not — because I genuinely believe that a court would agree with me.

Comment: @Jen That's nitpicking. In court cases, where the difference is immaterial, it is tantamount to "exactly the same".